# Adding new admin role programmatically don't work (Magento 2.3.1)

Tags: magento2, admin, role

I try to add a new role programmatically using this code :

```
<?php 
    namespace ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Setup; 

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface; 

    /* For get RoleType and UserType for create Role */; 
    use Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\Role\Group as RoleGroup;
    use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
    /** * @codeCoverageIgnore */ 

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface { 

    /** * RoleFactory * * @var roleFactory */ 
    private $roleFactory; 

    /** * RulesFactory * * @var rulesFactory */ 
    private $rulesFactory; 

    /** * Init * * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\RulesFactory $rulesFactory */ 

    public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory, /* Instance of Role*/
 \Magento\Authorization\Model\RulesFactory $rulesFactory /* Instance of Rule */ 
/*this define that which resource permitted to wich role */ ) { 
    $this->roleFactory = $roleFactory; 
    $this->rulesFactory = $rulesFactory; 
    } 

    /** * {@inheritdoc} * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength) */ 

    public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
    /** * Create Warehouse role */
   $role=$this->roleFactory->create();
   $role->setName('YourRoleName') //Set Role Name Which you want to create 

   ->setPid(0) //set parent role id of your role 
   ->setRoleType(RoleGroup::ROLE_TYPE) 
   ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN); 

    $role->save(); 
    /* Now we set that which resources we allow to this role */ $resource=[
        'Magento_Backend::admin',
                    'Magento_Sales::sales'
       ]; 

    /* Array of resource ids which we want to allow this role*/ 
    $this->rulesFactory->create()->setRoleId($role->getId())->setResources($resource)->saveRel(); 
    } 
    }
```

and I run the `setup:upgrade` command, but when I go to the User roles I can't found it.

PS: my module setup is `'0.0.0.1'`

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deleting the row modul on `setup_model` table on database